# Высчитать ширину блоков на JS и присвоить атрибут

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

Добрый день!

У меня есть верстка страницы, исходники https://www.dropbox.com/s/1v6o7f6pyblj0n6/page.rar?dl=0

1. на странице есть блок div c классом content-wrapper, его ширина резиновая.
2. так же есть div с классом navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom

Задача:

мне нужно с помощью JS вычислить ширину страницы в пискелях, потом вычислить разницу ширины страницы и content-wrapper, тоже в пикселях. а потом полученную цифру присвоить диву c классом navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom в виде атрибута style="left: X px;" где X наше полученное число.

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: Постарайтесь вставить минимальный код в тело вопроса, ссылка никому тут не нужна.

Comment: А точно ширину экрана? Может вы имели в виду ширину страницы?

Comment: верно, страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем виде это можно сделать так:

```
var pageWidth = document.body.offsetWidth; //получаем ширину страницы
var divWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('content-wrapper')[0].offsetWidth; //получаем ширину дива
var navLeft = pageWidth-divWidth; //высчитываем нужный отступ

var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0];
nav.style.left = navLeft+'px'; //задаём отступ навбару
```

А чтобы это работало при изменении размеров экрана, просто копируем почти всё внутрь функции window.onresize:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    pageWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
    divWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('content-wrapper')[0].offsetWidth;
    navLeft = pageWidth-divWidth;
    nav.style.left = navLeft+'px';
};
```

Comment: ширина content-wrapper зависит от sidebar, если он есть content-wrapper на всю ширину, минус sidebar. а если sidebar нет на страницы он 100% ширины страницы. но дело в том что sidebar может быть одни, два или полтора, то есть один к примеру свернут а один отрыт. Задача состоит только в том чтоб footer был шириной точно такой же как и content-wrapper

Comment: @verstala, ну ок, Вы можете использовать решение, которое я предложил. Единственное, что этот вариант сработает один раз при загрузке страницы. Если же количество sidebar'ов (один, два или полтора) у Вас меняется динамически, то изменения размеров надо каждый раз отлавливать и обновлять по какому-то событию (клик там или ещё что-то).

Comment: Ваш вариант работает, вот только он не работает динамически. то есть если я меняю ширину sidebar без перезагрузки страницы, ширина navbar не меняется. а мне нужно что ширина navbar менялась динамически.

Comment: @verstala, так я же написал Вам, что надо делать - Вы прочитали мой комментарий?

Comment: да, но ширина navbar должна меняться динамически, то есть если я сожму ширину браузера ширина navbar должна меняться

Comment: @verstala, ну, для этого существует функция onresize - я дополнил ответ.

Comment: благодарю! то что нужно.